# variable-sized object may not be initialized, c compilation error, but worked fine with c++

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I am trying to convert a c++ script to c. and in my main function I declared an array like the following:

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

        /* define how many integrals */
        const int n = 10;

        double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
        double a[n] = { -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0 };
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
test_code.c: In function ‘main’:
test_code.c:73:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
     double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
     ^
test_code.c:73:21: warning: excess elements in array initializer
     double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
                     ^
test_code.c:73:21: note: (near initialization for ‘b’)
test_code.c:73:26: warning: excess elements in array initializer
     double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
                          ^
test_code.c:73:26: note: (near initialization for ‘b’)
test_code.c:73:31: warning: excess elements in array initializer
     double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
```

and a lot of lines with the same error. This code was initially written for a c++ script and worked fine with no compilation error at all. I have the following libraries included:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Now I was wondering what might possible go wrong?
I was compiling with:

```
gcc -o test test_code.c
```

Comment: You just got the first hint that C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: and it's so irritating , I learnt c++ as my 2nd language, (python 1st), now converting everything to c is just a nightmare for me

Comment: And surprisingly, there are even more different languages: Pascal, Ada, PHP, Ruby, German, French, Chinese, Suaheli, ...